# How can I switch what points on an array equal in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

These change the array that I print to the screen. direc is an input before this. However, when array[1][2] == '#', it still moves '#' to array[1][0].

```
if (array[1][1] == '#' && direc == 'A' || direc == 'a' ) {
     array[1][1] = '_';
     array[1][0] = '#';
}
else {
    if (array[1][1] == '#' && direc == 'D' || direc == 'd' )  {
        array[1][1] = '_';
        array[1][2] = '#';
    }
    else {
        if (array[1][2] == '#' && direc == 'A' || direc == 'a'  ) {
            array[1][1] = '#';
            array[1][2] = '_';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[1][1] == '#' && direc == 'A' || direc == 'a' ` might need to change to `array[1][1] == '#' && (direc == 'A' || direc == 'a') `

Comment: `operator&&()` has higher precedence than `operator||()`. Without the parentheses proposed by @lucumt, the compiler would read this like `(array[1][1] == '#' && direc == 'A') || direc == 'a'` and that's probably not what you intended.

Comment: && operator has higher precedence than || operator. Specify the precedence you want with parentheses as mentioned by lucumt above.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add parentheses, as already noted in the comments, like this

```
if (array[1][1] == '#' && (direc == 'A' || direc == 'a' )) {
```

Alternatively you could use [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) in which case you no longer nee

```
if (array[1][1] == '#' && std::tolower(direc) == 'a') {
```

You could still add extra parentheses if you are not comfortable that operator && is lower precedence than operator ==

(the full table of operator precedences can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence))